# Clearing a tkinter embedded graph via a function

Tags: python, variables, matplotlib, graph

I would like the graph to be cleared upon the click of a tkinter button. The button should activate a function which clears the graph. I have created the following code, which does not work. When the `Clear()` function is ran, the graph does not get cleared. However, when I execute the code within the function outside of the function, it works.

Any ideas on how i can get the changes to `figure1` inside the function affect `figure1` outside the function? Or on how i can delete the whole canvas?

```
figure1 = Figure(figsize=(9.8,4.6),dpi=82)
ax = figure1.add_subplot(111)
width=.5
graph = ax.bar(books, occurences, width)

canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1, master=root)
canvas2.draw()
canvas2.get_tk_widget().place(in_=canvas, relx = 0.5, rely=0.44, anchor=CENTER)


def Clear():
    figure1.clf()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. The best way is to delete the whole canvas, seeing as the canvas is only being used to display the graph.

```
canvas.get_tk_widget().destroy()
```

Embedding this inside any function and then calling it will do the trick!